# Seeking young adult anthology title

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The anthology had several stories which I can't find.

- One story is about genetic accidents hidden from view. They are the result of genetic engineering. When the children escape, they are attacked. Later the main protagonist is offered to live among normals. He declines.
- Another story is about a the Lost Generation. After genetic experimentation human IQs increase, but some throwbacks occur. The main character wants starships to take the Lost Generation to another world.  The leaders deny it till after some minor acts of terror they relent.
- Another story is about human colonists on a world where horse faced humanoids warn them not to build buildings because the moons exhibit strong gravity when align. The aliens call the alignment Ladder of Souls.
- Another story is about a young man who stops a terrorist act against people who want to poison drug users on the millennium night activities. Another story is about children who are infected with all diseases, if they survive they are heroes

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143593/trying-to-find-the-name-of-a-sci-fi-anthology-book-or-just-the-titles-of-one-or (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like Roger Elwood's The Other Side of Tomorrow (review [here](http://billionlightyearbookshelf.com/reviews/othersideoftomorrow.shtml))

I think the stories you describe are:

- J Hunter Holly's "The Others"
- Joseph Green's "Let My People Go"
- Leigh Brackett's "Come Sing Down the Moons of Moravenn"
- Edward D. Hoch's "Night of the Millennium"