# Trying to find the name of a sci fi anthology book, or just the titles of one or more stories

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Okay, so here it goes. Over a decade ago I read a sci fi anthology book from my grade school's library. I would guess it was written in the 50's or early 60's but I could be wrong. There are 3 stories I vaguely remember.

1. I remember this one the most. Most kids are born really smart through some type of enhancements. But the protagonist, while not dumb, is born like a normal person. Normal people tend to be looked down on or stigmatized in this society and he grows up and despite having average intelligence, leads a revolution against the government that has been promoting these kinds of genetic mutations.
2. The only thing I know is that this story is set in the year 2000 on New Years Day. The title includes "the Year 2000" in it I'm fairly sure. But that's all I can remember about it.
3. The final story is the most vague in my mind. But it's a story about cars and possibly racing? The title might be a two word title, the something. That something being the title of the name of the people that drive/race? Like the Langoliers, although obviously not that. I've read that one.

I know the last 2 are really vague, but any info on the first one at least might lead me to find different collections it's been in if I can track it down.

Thanks for everything!

Comment: I think I read the same book, a few decades ago (also from a school library), but I can't remember the story titles either. One thing that might help jog someone's memory: In your Story #1, I don't think the narrator was leading a "revolution" in the sense of trying to overthrow the government. I think he started a movement to petition for all the "normal" young people to be given a huge starship which they could use to go colonize another Earth-like planet where they would not feel "obsolete and useless." In other words, a simple separation of the two breeds of humanity.

Comment: Also, FYI if my answer is not correct: Story #1 that you mentioned may be "Kindness" by Lester del Rey, which has a similar premise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe the collection you are looking for may be *[The Other Side of Tomorrow](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?44950)*, published 1973, editor Roger Elwood.

The stories you would be thinking of may be:

1. "Let My People Go" by Joseph Green (see below)
2. "Night of the Millennium" by Edward D. Hoch ([previously asked and answered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122770/science-fiction-short-story-from-the-80s-called-night-of-the-millennium) here)
3. "The Speeders" by Arthur Tofte ([previously asked and answered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59606/seeking-short-story-about-teenage-hovercar-thieves-forced-to-race-to-their-death) here)

In fact, there appear to have been two other questions (in [Feb](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31924/looking-for-late-70s-short-story-anthology-wed-call-it-ya-now-may-have-includ) and [Aug](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39546/seeking-young-adult-anthology-title) 2013) for this same collection, though neither has a formally-accepted answer.

"Let My People Go" does not appear to be available online but is described in [an online review](http://www.rdrop.com/%7Ehalf/Personal/Stories/SickTomorrows.html) as:

> [T]he story of the last few genetic throwbacks in a future of perfect
> people. These normal children in a world of super-normals resort to
> their only weapon -- emotional manipulation -- to win their freedom.

A [different online review](https://myreadersblock.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/the-other-side-of-tomorrow-review.html) (from a blog called "My Reader's Block") provides summaries of all three stories:

> **"Let My People Go" by Joseph Green:** In this story humanity has been
> selecting for super intelligence.  However there are always some
> throwbacks born--"norms" as they are called.  The norms are always at
> a disadvantage, not just because of their lower intelligence quotient
> but also because of the restrictions and discrimination that they
> face. One norm, a poet, rises up as a voice for the oppressed and
> becomes a Moses for his kind--asking "Pharaoh" (the government of the
> su-norms) to build spaceships so he and his people can leave Earth and
> have place where they can be free.  Will the World Council agree?  Or
> will the norms be second-class citizens forever?

and

> **"Night of the Millennium" by Edward D. Hoch:** As the world prepares to
> celebrate the onset of the 2000s, a young man faces decisions about
> his career choice. As he tries to decide between becoming a laser
> surgeon like his father or a high-paying, high-profile job in
> communication engineering.  The man who is trying to recruit him gets
> caught up in a plot to cause a revolt at the millennium celebrations
> and Tommy (the young man) comes to his rescue....this causes Tommy to
> think about a third career choice.

and

> **"The Speeders" by Arthur Tofte:** In the world of the future, the
> government has supposedly ensured that vehicles will be safe--no
> speeding and no accidents.  But there are always the young joyriders
> who will find their way around the laws and restrictions.  These young
> men find that when thy joyride and manage to break the speeding laws
> one too many times that they are incarcerated--not in prison, but in
> Traverse Park. In what seems like a speed-demon's paradise, all bets
> are off.  The speeders can go as fast as they want and drive as
> recklessly as they want.  Is it really the freedom from restrictions
> that it appears? Or is there a more chilling motive behind the
> speeder's park?

Other questions about this collection have also referred to the following stories (these summaries also from "My Reader's Block"):

> **"The Others" by J. Hunter Holly:** Emelen and his friends have a very
> small world.  They are restricted to four walled areas and are
> instructed by the Voice.  The Voice teaches them everything they need
> to know and tells them exactly what to do and when to do it.  But
> Emelen is curious--where does the food they eat come from? How did
> they get where they are?  Why do all of his friends look different
> (different number of hands or eyes or mouths or legs...etc)?  One day
> he discovers the Others and the world changes.  Emelen finds a way to
> get a whole new world for his friends--and all the people who are like
> him.

and

> **"A Bowl of Biskies Makes a Growing Boy" by Raymond F. Jones:** Probably
> the darkest and most chilling of the stories.  A young man who hopes
> to be a biochemist one day makes a disturbing discovery about the
> additives in his morning breakfast cereal...and just about every other
> food item in his family's pantry. He soon realizes that the chemicals
> have been added to allow the population to be controlled. Those in
> power can't afford for him (and others who have discovered various
> other means of controlling the public--from subliminal messages to a
> secret organization that runs everything) to follow up on his
> knowledge and so he is quarantined with the other "troublemakers."
> But what will be his fate?

Comment: @TylerWood Thank you for coming back to confirm. Welcome to the site!